# console.log shows properties on empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing in react, and have a following function in one of my modules

```
export function fromURLQuery(str) {
  console.log('fromURLQuery BEGIN', str)
  let ret = {}
  if (!str) {
    console.log('fromURLQuery return empty', ret)
    return ret
  }
  if (str[0] === '?') str = str.slice(1, str.length)
  let vars = str.split('&')
  for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    let pair = vars[i].split('=')
    ret[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1])
    console.log('fromURLQuery', pair)
  }
  console.log('fromURLQuery return', ret)
  return ret
}
```

It gets executed in different parts of my application like this

```
let urlQuery = fromURLQuery(this.props.history.location.search)
```

The output in the console is

```
fromURLQuery BEGIN

====================================

fromURLQuery return empty
Object{
|   <prototype>: Object { … }
}
====================================

fromURLQuery BEGIN

====================================

fromURLQuery return empty
Object {
|   item: undefined
|   <prototype>: Object { … }
}
```

Basically, at the second call of the function `return ret`, returns non-empty object (with `item: undefined`) where it should be empty. There are lot of logic around and in between. I do not really know where to look. This behavior is consistent among firefox and chrome. Trying (`value.hasOwnProperty('item')` returns `false`), so it is only shown in the console.  Any ideas why `console.log` can show properties on "empty" object?

Comment: There should be code somewhere that looks like `console.log("item:", item);`

Comment: I hopefully improved the console output to make it more clear of what it means. Please, have a look.

Comment: Add the full URL or `str` parameter.

Comment: it is empty, you can see that at `if` `!str` is true.

Comment: That means falsy, not empty.

Comment: If it was anything else, but empty string, `console.log('fromURLQuery BEGIN', str)` would have printed it, as you can see in the console output it does not.

Comment: Your function works fine here in Chrome, except for the obvious flaws of `?` and `#`. This is either not the function you are using or not the log you actually get.

Comment: Without knowing what data you're actually trying to process it's impossible to guess. It's likely one (or more) assumptions you're making is incorrect.

Comment: Your console also logs `empty` if I pass the string `"empty"`, by the way. Just to ruin your argument.